# OpenMP seems not running in parallel

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying my first openmp program in c++, my code is:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
for (int i=0;i<16;++i)
{
    printf( "Thread %d works with idx %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);
}
```

I compiled with g++ -O3 -fopenmp -std=c++11

However, when I run the program, I got:

```
Thread 0 works with idx 0
Thread 0 works with idx 1
Thread 0 works with idx 2
Thread 0 works with idx 3
Thread 0 works with idx 4
Thread 0 works with idx 5
Thread 0 works with idx 6
Thread 0 works with idx 7
Thread 1 works with idx 8
Thread 1 works with idx 9
Thread 1 works with idx 10
Thread 1 works with idx 11
Thread 1 works with idx 12
Thread 1 works with idx 13
Thread 1 works with idx 14
Thread 1 works with idx 15
```

Is it running in parallel? I was expecting something like thread0 - thread1 - thread0 - thread1, one after another.

What would be the problem here?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is running in parallel. You can seen the IDs from two different threads being printed.

> I was expecting something like thread0 - thread1 - thread0 - thread1,
>   one after another.

Since you did not defined the scheduling of your parallel loop, by default it will divide the loop iterations into blocks and assign them to the threads. In your case `thread 0` have the block `from 0 to 7` and `thread 1` the block from `8 - 15`.

If you want threads to work in a round-robin fashion (one after the another) you have to declare a static parallel for with scheduling of chunk = 1, like : `#pragma omp parallel for schedule (static,1)`

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule (static,1) num_threads(2)
for (int i=0;i<16;++i)
{
    printf( "Thread %d works with idx %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);
}
```

More about the openMP Loop static Scheduling :

> Divide the loop into equal-sized chunks or as equal as possible in the
>   case where the number of loop iterations is not evenly divisible by
>   the number of threads multiplied by the chunk size. By default, chunk
>   size is loop_count/number_of_threads.Set chunk to 1 to interleave the
>   iterations.

Source : [OpenMP* Loop Scheduling](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-loop-scheduling)